# Giving Each Instance of a Class a Unique Identifier in a Multithreaded Environment

Tags: c++, multithreading, static

A common solution to giving each class a unique ID is to use a static member like so:

```
class Example {
   static unsigned int nextID;
   int id;
public:
   Example();
};

int Example::nextID = 0;

Example::Example () {
  id = nextID++;
}
```

Am I right in thinking that this is not safe in a multithreaded environment?
What is the correct solution? Should you simply use a lock guard on nextID in the constructor?

Comment: A factory class could help you with this

Comment: Odd that nextID is an `unsigned int`, but id is an `int`.

Comment: The objects address in memory could serve as a unique ID.

Comment: `#include <atomic>`, `static std::atomic<int> nextID;` `std::atomic<int> Example::nextID( 0 );`